# FT4232H - I2C connection

Tags: microcontroller, adc, i2c, digital-communications

I could not find I2C app note or pinout details in datasheet.
Based on my understanding i have drawn the I2C connection from FT4232H.

Is it my understanding is correct ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on the datasheet of this chip and the appnotes they link to, you have it correct.

Comment: Please provide detailed information on why it is correct, this isn't a very good answer

Comment: Thank you very much..

Answer (score 1):

According to Table 1 in ["AN_113 Interfacing FT2232H Hi-Speed Devices to I2C Bus"](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_113_FTDI_Hi_Speed_USB_To_I2C_Example.pdf) (FT2232H is just the 2-channel version of the FT4232H), your connections are correct:

[image]

Additionally, the ["USB to I²C Bus Interface - Sample Project"](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/MPSSE/FT2232C-Proj02_v11.pdf) document shows an example of using the FTx232x device as a USB-to-I2C converter.

[image]

Ignore the "Write Protect control output" - their example is controlling an external EEPROM using I2C. Note the pin numbers in this table will not match your device. Table 3.8  in the [FT4232H datasheet](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT4232H.pdf) is a more accurate representation:

[image]

Comment: Thanks ..I got it now